# Android app URL for Winter Bash

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

For the *Cutting the Cord* hat it is written:

> vote on seven questions or answers using the Android or iOS app

Do I have to use [this Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en) to earn it? If not, which is the correct Google play store URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the official app, developed by Stack Exchange.

[Here's the iOS version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8).

Comment: Nice app, nice site, keep the good work up, never lose faith!

Comment: @Liviu: I didn't make that app.